# Meaning of 'was' in "I was planning on it"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does the word ‘was’ mean in this phrase?

> I was planning on it.

Does it mean 'not anymore' or does it indicate 'intent' and mean 'will do'?

Comment: It's not the case that every word has a meaning; some have only uses. _Was_ is the singular first- and third-person form of the auxiliary verb _be_. In this sentence, it's the auxiliary verb for the Progressive construction _be planning_. So _was_ in this sentence marks the past tense of the Progressive. It has no meaning of its own, any more than _has_ in _has gone_ -- it's just the marker for that particular construction.

Comment: @JohnLawler I think you're taking "meaning" too literally, he's just asking what the function of "was" is, and how it changes the sense of the verb. In particular, does it imply that they're no longer planning on it.

Comment: It certainly can be used in that context, among others, but it isn't limited to it. You could say it invites the inference he's no longer doing it, but not that it implies it.

Comment: This is a good question. *was planning* and *have been planning* and *am planning* can all mean the same thing, depending on the context and intonation.

Answer (score 2):

Out of context it's ambiguous as to whether they're still planning on it or not. For instance, this is a possible conversation:

> Q: Are you going to the dance?
> A: Yes, I was planning on it.
> Q: I'm sorry to tell you that it's been cancelled.

But so is this:

> Q: Are you going to the dance?
> A: I was planning on it, but then something better came up.

Comment: There's a connotation at least of frustration where context doesn't (eg your examples) preclude it. '[Oh no!] I was planning on it being my pension fund.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There are lots of different possible situations. In the cases where the plan changes, it all depends on whether the change was in your control or not. "I was planning on going to X, but there was so much traffic I was too late."